# Show admin help message across custom post type parent and child posts

Tags: custom-post-types, admin, notifications

In my custom plugin, I am using the following code to display an info / help box.

This is working great for the main admin edit screen that lists the custom posts, but how can I extend this to show the message at the top of each of the actual child custom posts too.

```
function my_admin_notice(){
global $pagenow;
if ($_GET['post_type'] == 'my_custom_post_type' ) {
 echo '
     <div class="updated">
     <h3><strong>Help</strong></h3>
     <p>some help text</p>   
     </div>';
}
}
add_action('admin_notices', 'my_admin_notice');
```

Comment: Not directly related, but take a look at [`contextual_help`](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/search?q=contextual_help) to add your own help topics in the Help tab, or even replace the defaults.

Comment: No, that is not helpful at all and is not relevant to my question. I'm not looking for contextual help functionality. I already have a help message displaying just fine, I simply need it to show on child posts as well. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to check the `$pagenow` variable and the post type of the post being edited. It will look something like this:

```
function wpse_75224_admin_notices() {
    global $pagenow;

    $is_edit_custom_post_type = ( 'post.php ' == $pagenow && 'my_custom_post_type' == get_post_type( $_GET['post'] ) );
    $is_new_custom_post_type = ( 'post-new.php' == $pagenow && 'my_custom_post_type' == $_GET['post_type'] );
    $is_all_post_type = ( 'edit.php' == $pagenow && 'my_custom_post_type' == $_GET['post_type'] );

    if ( $is_all_post_type || $is_edit_custom_post_type || $is_new_custom_post_type ) {
        echo "Your message.";
    }
}

add_action( 'admin_notices', 'wpse_75224_admin_notices' );
```

Comment: Thank you for your fast response and effort, but this still does not work on the child posts.  FYI the child posts are not displaying the parent post type name, instead they look like this: wp-admin/post.php?post=146&action=edit

Comment: @Sol, use `global $pagenow, $post;` and get the information you need from `$post`, like: `$post->post_parent`.